# Sequence of square numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do I prove that the following sequence is always a perfect square?
729, 71289, 7112889, 711128889, 71111288889...
I tried proving it by induction however it got me nowhere. So, it would be great if I could get some help. Probably a generalization to solve similar questions would be of more help rather than this single example.

Comment: What do you think these are the squares of?

Comment: I don't understand what the sequence is supposed to be at a quick glance.  Please clarify.  It looks like you have a $7$ followed by some number of $1$'s, then either a $2$ or an $8$, followed by whichever you didn't choose the same number of times as you had used $1$'s, followed by a $9$.  What makes you choose a $2$ rather than an $8$ for the middle term?

Comment: $\sqrt{711\color{red}{822}9}$ is not an integer.  $\sqrt{711\color{red}{288}9}$ is however.

Comment: @lulu and yet the question has the 8's and 2's swapped in several places, hence my question.

Comment: @JMoravitz  Right, I noticed that at some point.  Anyway, I'm pretty sure the OP intended to write $\left(26^{n-1}7\right)^2$.

Answer (score 4):

Your third number isn't square; I think the question meant $729, 71289, 7112889, 711128889, 71111288889$. The square roots then begin $27, 267, 2667, 26667, 266667$. We'll number terms from $n=0$, so you want to prove $(26\cdots6 7)^2=71\cdots128\cdots89$, where $k\cdots k$ is an abbreviation for $n$ copies of the digit $k$. Equivalently,$$\left(2\times 10^{n+1}+\frac{20}{3}(10^n-1)+7\right)^2\\=7\times 10^{2n+2}+10^{n+2}\frac{10^n-1}{9}+2\times 10^{n+1}+\frac{80}{9}(10^n-1)+9.$$Can you take it from there?

Comment: Thankyou verymuch. Now I need to proove LHS=RHS right?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you mean the following. $$7\cdot10^{2n}+1\cdot\frac{10^{n-1}-1}{9}\cdot10^{n+1}+2\cdot10^n+8\cdot\frac{10^{n-1}-1}{9}\cdot10+9=\left(\frac{8\cdot10^n+1}{3}\right)^2$$

Comment: Thankyou very much. Now I need to proove RHS=LHS right? How do I do that exactly? Or this is the solution itself. I am confused because you have turned the words into figure but is this the proof itself?

Comment: @Akil You should prove the identity. To do so, expand the RHS, multiply both sides by $9$, then verify the difference between the two sides simplifies to $0$.